# Вставить результаты if

Tags: php

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
      $body .= '<b>Результат:</b> ' . 'ВСТАВИТЬ РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ IF сюда' . '<br>';
      
      if($thisEvent['orderYesterday'] >= $thisEvent['orderTtoday']){
        $uspeh = "<p style=\"color:red\">( " . $thisEvent = $thisEvent['orderYesterday'] - $thisEvent['orderTtoday'] . " )</p>";
      } else{
        $nouspeh = "<p style=\"color:blue\">( " . $thisEvent = $thisEvent['orderTtoday'] - $thisEvent['orderYesterday'] . " )</p>";
      }
```

Не пойму как вставить результаты в первую строку (указал куда именно нужно). Пробовал вставить if целиком, но выходит белый экран без ошибок.

Comment: $body вынести ниже if; дать одно имя переменной, а не разные, как сейчас; вместо `'ВСТАВИТЬ РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ IF сюда'` использовать ту самую переменную

Comment: Блин я делал так, но писал if снизу, поэтому не получалось. Сейчас сделал сверху, результат есть. Но, у меня есть ещё несколько $body снизу и все они выводят теперь результаты этого if.

Comment: Значит что-то не так делаете

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю что за проблема была, но грамотно сделать так:

```
  if (condition) {
    $success = "STRING 1";
  } else {
    $success = "STRING 2";
  }

  $body .= '<b>Результат:</b> '.success.'<br>';
```